# How to create a shared variable in perl(array of hashes)

Tags: multithreading, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Perl: Threading with shared multi-dimensional hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702024/perl-threading-with-shared-multi-dimensional-hash)

I have a piece of code that looks something like this(oversimplified):

```
my @arr;
foreach $t (1..8){
     load_arr($t);
}

sub load_arr{
    my ($t) = @_;
    #get some data form somewhere
    #and put it into $a, $b, $c, $d
    $arr[$t]{$a}{$b}{$c} = $d;
}
```

load_arr actually takes a long time since its looping over a large dataset(loop not shown for simplicity)

I want to rewrite the code to look something like this.

```
my @arr :shared;
my @threads;
foreach $t (1..8){
    push @threads, threads->create(\&load_arr,$t);
}
$->join for @threads;
....
```

The problem is when I run it, I get the following errors:

```
Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar at ...
```

I am looking for some help as to how to properly share these?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that one. will give it a try.

Comment: I agree with Greg Bacon. Same problem, and the answers apply. See also [Threading: Invalid value for shared scalar](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=259551) on PerlMonks.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use threads;
use threads::shared;
my  @ThreadInput  :shared=();
```

@ThreadInput is visible to all threads spawened in my script.